# define new variables and assign values by using text file

Tags: java

In shell script, I can use a loop to set new variables from a text file which contains variables and values. My text file looks like:

```
path1=/tmp/data 
path2=/tmp/data2 
myname=ABC
```

In java, is there any way to do like that?

Comment: take a look at java.util.Properties

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you can probably use a mechanism to read the file using BufferedReader or Files from NIO and obtain the variables you want. If you want a more "key - value" structure you can save the variables in a map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it is quite a common practice. Many server-based applications are designed in a way that they can fetch such variables from a file rather than a database. 
These two links are all you'll need to get started:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html